# Symfony 2 Persist multiple entities in one form

Tags: symfony

I work on a symfony 2 app and I need some help to resolve a case I never had before.

My app has only one page with multiple blocs. Let's consider animals for a simple example. On my page, I have a first bloc where I show N dogs with all their caracteristics, then a second bloc where I show rabbits, then a third bloc with cats ect.

I also have an admin page where the user may modify the displayed data on the main page. The problem I have is that I must use **only one** page to admin all the blocs. That means that I have N dog, M rabbits, P cats entities displayed on my admin page and when I submit my form, Symfony must delete, update or insert each entity in database.

To do so, I created an entity and a formType for each animal, and a mapped superclass called Website with arraycollections for each entity.

**Website Entity :**

```
/**
 * Website
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass()
 */
class Website
{

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    private $dogs;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    private $rabbits;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    private $cats;

    ...
}
```

**Website Type :**

```
class WebsiteType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('dogs',        'collection', array(
                'type'         => new DogType(),
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ))
            ->add('rabbits',    'collection', array(
                'type'         => new RabbitType(),
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ))
            ->add('cats',   'collection', array(
                'type'         => new CatType(),
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ))
            ->add('save',           'submit')
        ;
    }
}
```

**In my controller :**

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$dogs = $manager->getRepository('MyBundle:Dog')->findAll();
$rabbits = $manager->getRepository('MyBundle:Rabbit')->findAll();
$cats = $manager->getRepository('MyBundle:Cat')->findAll();

$website = new Website();
$website->setDogs($dogs);
$website->setRabbits($rabbits);
$website->setCats($cats);

$form = $this->createForm(new WebsiteType(), $website);

if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
    $manager->persist($website);
    $manager->flush();
}

return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:admin.html.twig', array(
    'form'    => $form->createView(),
    'website' => $website
));
```

When I submit the form, I have this error :

> The given entity of type 'MyBundle\Entity\Website'
>   (MyBundle\Entity\Website@0000000040d8aeb900007fd77a072110) has no
>   identity/no id values set. It cannot be added to the identity map.

What should I do ?

Comment: You want to persist `website` class, but it's not mapped to database.

Comment: Your Website doesn't seem to be an entity, where is the @ORM\Entity annotation ? Where is the primary key (E.g. an ID property with @ORM\Id) ?

Comment: That's indeed the problem : I don't want website to be persisted because I have only one website. I just created this class to have only one object passed to the form, to do only one createForm(), and only one handleRequest.

Otherwise how could I do the handleRequest for the N instances of the M classes ?

Comment: You could try a slightly different approach where, instead of trying to save all entities in a single submit, you have a save button for each animal and then use an ajax call to submit the 'animal specific' form to an 'animal specific' controller action?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do that, my customer insisted on his need to have an unique button to submit the page... :(